# Incentre geometry question

Tags: geometry

[image: The image for the question]I is the incentre of triangle ABC.  X and Y are feet of the perpendiculars from A to BI and CI.  Prove that XY is parallel to BC

Comment: A sketch would be very usefull....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Diagram]

Extend $AX$ to cut $BC$ at $P$. Do the similar thing to the line $AYQ$.

Prove that$ \triangle ABX$ and $\triangle PBX$ are congruent. Similarly, $\triangle ACY$ and $\triangle QCY$ are congruent.

Thus. $X$ and $Y$ are the midpoints of $AP$ and $AQ$ respectively.

Then $XY\ ||\ CB$,  by midpoint theorem.